# Recursion Product mips32

Tags: recursion, assembly, mips, product, multiplication

The code isn't printing the product of 2 numbers. I am not sure how to print out the result. I'm not 100% sure if my return value is store in stack pointer or not.

```
main:


        #prompt 1
        li $v0, 4        # Print the String at Label “Input”
                la $a0, num1
                syscall
                li $v0, 5                      
                syscall
                move $a2, $v0

        #prompt 2
        li $v0, 4     # Print the String at Label “Input”
                la $a0, num2
                syscall
                li $v0, 5      # Read integer from user
                syscall
        move $a1, $v0  # Pass integer to input argument register $a0

        jal multiply       

        add $a0, $v0, $zero
            li  $v0, 1
        syscall


multiply:

            bne $a1, 0, recurse  
            move $v1, $a1
            jr $ra

recurse:

    sub $sp, $sp, 12
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    sw $a0, 4($sp)
    sw $a1, 8($sp)

    addiu $a1, $a1, -1
    jal multiply

        lw $a1, 4($sp)
        add $v1, $v1, $a1

        lw $ra, 0($sp)
        addi $sp, $sp, 12
        jr $ra
```

Expected value of 3 * 2 is 6, but prints out 2. 3 * 3 returns 3

Comment: **Some** value should be printed if that piece of code is reached. It's just a wrong value because your function returns value in `$v1` not `$v0`. Also, you fall through into `multiply` because you don't have an exit syscall (but that should not affect printing).

Comment: There's no need to save anything except `$ra` on the stack in this case. After the recursive `jal multiply` you can simply do `addu $v0,$a0,$v0` (and as @Jester hinted, that `move $v1, $a1` should be `move $v0, $a1`).

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. It's printing an address value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive product mips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55859580/recursive-product-mips)