# Recursive product mips

Tags: recursion, mips, mips32

I made some changes to the code, but it is still printing a 9digit number. Not sure what's going on here. When I type in 2 * 3, it outputs 268501017. Im having a hard time find out how to get the result from the register and print it.

```
    main:


            #prompt 1
            li $v0, 4        # Print the String at Label “Input”
            la $a0, num1
            syscall
            li $v0, 5                      
            syscall
            move $a2, $v0

            #prompt 2
            li $v0, 4     # Print the String at Label “Input”
            la $a0, num2
            syscall
            li $v0, 5      # Read integer from user
            syscall
            move $a1, $v0  # Pass integer to input argument register $a0

            jal multiply       

            add $a1, $v0, $zero
            li  $v0, 1
            syscall

        li $v0, 10
        syscall

    multiply:

            bne $a1, 0, recurse  
            move $v0, $a1
            jr $ra

    recurse:

        sub $sp, $sp, 12
            sw $ra, 0($sp)
            sw $a0, 4($sp)
            sw $a1, 8($sp)

        addiu $a1, $a1, -1 #product(x, y-1)
            jal multiply

            lw $a1, 4($sp)
            add $v0, $a2, $a1

            lw $ra, 0($sp)
            addi $sp, $sp, 12
            jr $ra
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing a memory address, not the result of your calculation.

This is due to reusing `$a0` which is still holding the address of `num1`. You should store just the two operands in `$a0` and `$a1` if that is all that is needed for `multiply`.

Also, your add instruction does not use the result from the previous recursive call. It instead uses the two argument registers.

Finally, syscall 1 prints the number in `$a0`, not `$a1`

So:

1. `move $a2, $v0` should be `move $a1, $v0` (line 10)
2. `move $a1, $v0` should be `move $a0, $v0` (line 18)
3. `add $a1, $v0, $zero` should be `add $a0, $v0, $zero` (line 22)
4. `add $v0, $a2, $a1` should be `add $v0, $v0, $a1` (line 46)